How to Implement a Custom Undo and Redo Feature in an Android App Without Using an EditText?
I’m working on an Android app where users can make changes to a canvas (e.g., drawing shapes, moving objects, or changing colors). I want to implement Undo and Redo functionality, but most tutorials I’ve found focus on text input with EditText.
In my case, the actions to undo or redo are more complex, like:

Undoing a shape being drawn.
Redoing a shape that was previously undone.
Undoing property changes (e.g., resizing or color adjustments).

Here’s the approach I’m considering:

Storing each action (like "add shape" or "change color") as an object in a Stack.
Using one stack for Undo and another for Redo.
Applying or reversing actions based on user input (e.g., button clicks).

However, I’m not sure about:

The best way to structure these action objects to handle different types of changes.
How to manage memory efficiently if the user performs a large number of actions.
Whether there’s a better design pattern (e.g., Command pattern) to handle this kind of functionality.

If anyone has implemented something similar or can point me to resources, I’d love to hear your thoughts!

You can take a look at Editor.java and UndoManager.java from Android SDK if you look for inspiration. The way to go with this I guess would be to have an "ActionUndo" interface with methods undo and redo and then have different classes like TransformationUndo implement this.
I don't have much experience with this, but that's how I'd approach it.

See other threads too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969746/how-to-efficiently-implement-undo-history-for-images
